# Hive: Better way to rewrite this hive query

Tags: sql, hadoop, join, hive, query-optimization

First of all, sorry for this big query. I've been following many guides on how to optimise the long join query. and not able to put my head in the correct place

Any way, the following are my spec
Main records in table

```
dre_output: 38891075
item_tbl: 558991075
```

Basically what the query does is, get the input from `dre_output` and join with item table(`item_tbl`) and filter not good items. and finally prepare the output

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE service1_db.bottle_input PARTITION (dt = '${final_date}')
SELECT
sq3.user_id as user_id,
item_image_converter_udf(sq3.imgpath [0]),
itemname_converter_udf(sq3.itname [0]),
sq3.itprice [0],
CONCAT('https://image.example/',sq3.shopurl [0],'/logo/logo2xq.jpg'),
CONCAT('https://www.example.com/item/', sq3.shopurl [0]),sq3.imp_url [0],sq3.click_url [0],item_image_converter_udf(sq3.imgpath [1]),
itemname_converter_udf(sq3.itname [1]),sq3.itprice [1],CONCAT(    'https://image.example/',
sq3.shopurl [1],
'/logo/logo2xq.jpg'
),
CONCAT('https://www.example.com/item/', sq3.shopurl [1]),
sq3.imp_url [1],
sq3.click_url [1],
item_image_converter_udf(sq3.imgpath [2]),
itemname_converter_udf(sq3.itname [2]),
sq3.itprice [2],
CONCAT(
'https://image.example/',
sq3.shopurl [2],
'/logo/logo2xq.jpg'
),
CONCAT('https://www.example.com/item/', sq3.shopurl [2]),
sq3.imp_url [2],
sq3.click_url [2],
item_image_converter_udf(sq3.imgpath [3]),
itemname_converter_udf(sq3.itname [3]),
sq3.itprice [3],
CONCAT(
'https://image.example/',
sq3.shopurl [3],
'/logo/logo2xq.jpg'
),
CONCAT('https://www.example.com/item/', sq3.shopurl [3]),
sq3.imp_url [3],
sq3.click_url [3],
item_image_converter_udf(sq3.imgpath [4]),
itemname_converter_udf(sq3.itname [4]),
sq3.itprice [4],
CONCAT(
'https://image.example/',
sq3.shopurl [4],
'/logo/logo2xq.jpg'
),
CONCAT('https://www.example.com/item/', sq3.shopurl [4]),
sq3.imp_url [4],
sq3.click_url [4],
item_image_converter_udf(sq3.imgpath [5]),
itemname_converter_udf(sq3.itname [5]),
sq3.itprice [5],
CONCAT(
'https://image.example/',
sq3.shopurl [5],
'/logo/logo2xq.jpg'
),
CONCAT('https://www.example.com/item/', sq3.shopurl [5]),
sq3.imp_url [5],
sq3.click_url [5],
item_image_converter_udf(sq3.imgpath [6]),
itemname_converter_udf(sq3.itname [6]),
sq3.itprice [6],
CONCAT(
'https://image.example/',
sq3.shopurl [6],
'/logo/logo2xq.jpg'
),
CONCAT('https://www.example.com/item/', sq3.shopurl [6]),
sq3.imp_url [6],
sq3.click_url [6],
item_image_converter_udf(sq3.imgpath [7]),
itemname_converter_udf(sq3.itname [7]),
sq3.itprice [7],
CONCAT(
'https://image.example/',
sq3.shopurl [7],
'/logo/logo2xq.jpg'
),
CONCAT('https://www.example.com/item/', sq3.shopurl [7]),
sq3.imp_url [7],
sq3.click_url [7],
ARRAY(
NAMED_STRUCT('shop_id', sq3.merchantlist [0],'item_id',sq3.itemid [0]),
NAMED_STRUCT('shop_id', sq3.merchantlist [1],'item_id',sq3.itemid [1]),
NAMED_STRUCT('shop_id', sq3.merchantlist [2],'item_id',sq3.itemid [2]),
NAMED_STRUCT('shop_id', sq3.merchantlist [3],'item_id',sq3.itemid [3]),
NAMED_STRUCT('shop_id', sq3.merchantlist [4],'item_id',sq3.itemid [4]),
NAMED_STRUCT('shop_id', sq3.merchantlist [5],'item_id',sq3.itemid [5]),
NAMED_STRUCT('shop_id', sq3.merchantlist [6],'item_id',sq3.itemid [6]),
NAMED_STRUCT('shop_id', sq3.merchantlist [7],'item_id',sq3.itemid [7])
)
FROM(
SELECT
campaingId,
user_id,
imgpath,
itname,
itprice,
shopurl,
lg_id,
ARRAY(
click_url_converter_udf(campaingId[0],shopid[0],user_id,itemid[0],lg_id,'prod','${final_date}','server1'),
click_url_converter_udf(campaingId[1],shopid[1],user_id,itemid[1],lg_id,'prod','${final_date}','server1'),
click_url_converter_udf(campaingId[2],shopid[2],user_id,itemid[2],lg_id,'prod','${final_date}','server1'),
click_url_converter_udf(campaingId[3],shopid[3],user_id,itemid[3],lg_id,'prod','${final_date}','server1'),
click_url_converter_udf(campaingId[4],shopid[4],user_id,itemid[4],lg_id,'prod','${final_date}','server1'),
click_url_converter_udf(campaingId[5],shopid[5],user_id,itemid[5],lg_id,'prod','${final_date}','server1'),
click_url_converter_udf(campaingId[6],shopid[6],user_id,itemid[6],lg_id,'prod','${final_date}','server1'),
click_url_converter_udf(campaingId[7],shopid[7],user_id,itemid[7],lg_id,'prod','${final_date}','server1')
) AS click_url,
ARRAY(
imp_url_converter_udf(campaingId[0],merchantlist[0],user_id,shopurl[0],itemid[0],lg_id, "1", 'prod'),
imp_url_converter_udf(campaingId[1],merchantlist[1],user_id,shopurl[1],itemid[1],lg_id, "2", 'prod'),
imp_url_converter_udf(campaingId[2],merchantlist[2],user_id,shopurl[2],itemid[2],lg_id, "3", 'prod'),
imp_url_converter_udf(campaingId[3],merchantlist[3],user_id,shopurl[3],itemid[3],lg_id, "4", 'prod'),
imp_url_converter_udf(campaingId[4],merchantlist[4],user_id,shopurl[4],itemid[4],lg_id, "5", 'prod'),
imp_url_converter_udf(campaingId[5],merchantlist[5],user_id,shopurl[5],itemid[5],lg_id, "6", 'prod'),
imp_url_converter_udf(campaingId[6],merchantlist[6],user_id,shopurl[6],itemid[6],lg_id, "7", 'prod'),
imp_url_converter_udf(campaingId[7],merchantlist[7],user_id,shopurl[7],itemid[7],lg_id, "8", 'prod')
) AS imp_url,
itemid,
merchantlist from
(select
user_id,
lg_id,
sortIntScore_udf(itemid, scores) AS itemid,
sortIntScore_udf(shopids, scores) AS merchantlist,
sortStrScore_udf(shopid, scores) AS shopid,
sortStrScore_udf(campaingId, scores) AS campaingId,
sortStrScore_udf(imgpath, scores) AS imgpath,
sortStrScore_udf(itname, scores) AS itname,
sortIntScore_udf(itprice, scores) AS itprice,
sortStrScore_udf(shopurl, scores) AS shopurl
from
(select
  dre.user_id,
  dre.lg_id,
  COLLECT_LIST(dre.item_id) AS itemid,
  COLLECT_LIST(dre.score) AS scores,
  COLLECT_LIST(dre.shop_id) AS shopids,
  COLLECT_LIST(camp.shop_id) AS shopid,
  COLLECT_LIST(camp.id) AS campaingId,
  COLLECT_LIST(item_tbl.image_path1) AS imgpath,
  COLLECT_LIST(item_tbl.itemname) AS itname,
  COLLECT_LIST(item_tbl.item_price) AS itprice,
  COLLECT_LIST(item_tbl.shop_url) AS shopurl
from
  (
    SELECT
      user_id,
      lg_id,
      view.item_id,
      view.shop_id,
      view.score
    FROM
      service1_db.dre_output LATERAL VIEW POSEXPLODE(rvd) v AS pos,
      view
    WHERE
      date_val = '${input_date}'
      AND target_id = 0
  ) aog
  INNER JOIN service2_db.campaign camp ON (dre.shop_id = camp.shop_id)
  AND camp.bcc = "1"
  AND camp.bcc_id = "2"
  AND camp.dt = "${input_date}" AND camp.hh = "${input_hour}"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN(
    SELECT
      id,
      start_datetime,
      end_datetime
    from
      service2_db.shop_not_good_tbl
    WHERE
      '${final_date}' BETWEEN TO_DATE(FROM_UTC_TIMESTAMP(start_datetime, 'IST'))
      AND TO_DATE(FROM_UTC_TIMESTAMP(end_datetime, 'IST'))
      AND bcc = "1"
      AND bcc_id = "2"
      AND date_val = "${input_date}" AND hour = "${input_hour}"
  ) as cbs ON camp.shop_id = cbs.id
  Inner join(
    SELECT
      image_path1,
      itemname,
      item_price,
      itemdec,
      genre_id,
      shop_url,
      item_id,
      shop_id,
      start_time,
      end_time
    from
      service2_db.item_tbl
    WHERE
      item_status = 1
      AND (
        rpp_ng = 0
        OR rpp_ng IS NULL
      )
      AND (
        timesales_flg = 0
        OR (
          timesales_flg = 1
          AND getDateFromTimeMacro(start_time) <= '${final_date}'
          AND getDateFromTimeMacro(end_time) >= '${offer_end_date}'
        )
      )
      AND (
        (
          market_type = 100
          AND search_disable_flg = 0
        )
        OR (
          market_type = 110
          AND pre_search_disable_flg = 0
        )
        AND bcc = "1"
        AND bcc_id = "2"
        AND date_val = "${input_date}" AND hour = "${input_hour}"
      )
  ) as item_tbl ON (
    dre.item_id = item_tbl.item_id
    AND dre.shop_id = item_tbl.shop_id
  )
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
      shop_id,
      item_id
    FROM
      service2_db.item_not_good_tbl
    WHERE
      bcc = "1"
      AND bcc_id = "2"
      AND date_val = "${input_date}" AND hour = "${input_hour}"
  ) AS rppbi ON rppbi.shop_id = item_tbl.shop_id
  AND rppbi.item_id = item_tbl.item_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
      value,
      type
    FROM
      service2_db.filter_tbl
    WHERE
      channel = "bbc" AND bcc = "1"
      AND bcc_id = "2"
      AND date_val = "${input_date}" AND hour = "${input_hour}"
  ) AS fltr_tbl ON (
    dre.shop_id = fltr_tbl.value
    AND fltr_tbl.type = "type1"
  )
  OR (
    item_tbl.shop_url = fltr_tbl.value
    AND fltr_tbl.type = "type2"
  )
  OR (
    (
      (item_tbl.itemname) LIKE CONCAT('%', (fltr_tbl.value), '%')
      AND fltr_tbl.type = "type3"
    )
    OR (
      (item_tbl.itemdec) LIKE CONCAT('%', (fltr_tbl.value), '%')
      AND fltr_tbl.type = "type3"
    )
  )
  OR (
    item_tbl.genre_id = fltr_tbl.value
    AND fltr_tbl.type = "type4"
  )
WHERE
  cbs.id IS NULL
  AND rppbi.shop_id IS NULL
  AND fltr_tbl.value IS NULL
GROUP BY
  dre.user_id,
  dre.lg_id) sq1
WHERE SIZE(sq1.itemid) >= 5
) sq2
) sq3;
```

And below are hive properties for optimization

```
set hive.execution.engine=tez
set hive.auto.convert.join=true;
set hive.optimize.skewjoin=true;
SET hive.tez.container.size=18432;
SET tez.runtime.unordered.output.buffer.size-mb=2048
SET tez.runtime.io.sort.mb=7372; -- 40% of tez.container size
SET hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask.size=8589934592; -- 8GB
SET hive.tez.java.opts=-Xmx8192m -Xms8192m;
SET tez.am.launch.cmd-opts=-Xmx6554m -Xms6554m;
set hive.ignore.mapjoin.hint=false;
SET hive.exec.parallel=true;
SET hive.exec.parallel.thread.number=10;
SET hive.exec.compress.intermediate=true;
set mapred.reduce.tasks=-1;
set mapreduce.map.output.compress=true;
set mapreduce.map.output.compress.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec;
SET hive.vectorized.execution.enabled=true;
SET hive.vectorized.execution.reduce.enabled=true;
SET hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=1073741824; --1GB
SET hive.merge.size.per.task=260217728;
SET hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize=2831155200;
SET hive.merge.tezfiles=true;
SET hive.merge.mapfiles=true;
SET hive.merge.mapredfiles=true;
SET hive.mapred.mode=nostrict;
set tez.am.resource.memory.mb=10240;
set tez.task.resource.memory.mb=10240;
set hive.vectorized.execution.reduce.groupby.enabled=true;
set hive.cbo.enable=true;
set hive.exec.compress.output=true;
SET hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize=2831155200;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
```

Obviously, I've been following issues when running the query

1. java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
2. Halting due to Out Of Memory Error...

Tez info

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        VERTICES      MODE        STATUS  TOTAL  COMPLETED  RUNNING  PENDING  FAILED  KILLED
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        VERTICES      MODE        STATUS  TOTAL  COMPLETED  RUNNING  PENDING  FAILED  KILLED
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        VERTICES      MODE        STATUS  TOTAL  COMPLETED  RUNNING  PENDING  FAILED  KILLED
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Map 1 .......... container     SUCCEEDED    149        149        0        0       0       0
Map 5 .......... container     SUCCEEDED     23         23        0        0       0       0
Map 9 .......... container     SUCCEEDED     25         25        0        0       0       0
Reducer 2 .      container       RUNNING    100         25        0       75       0      83
Map 6            container  INITIALIZING     -1          0        0       -1       0       0
Map 7 .......... container     SUCCEEDED     21         21        0        0       0       0
Map 8 .......... container     SUCCEEDED     22         22        0        0       0       0
Reducer 3        container        INITED    100          0        0      100       0       0
Reducer 4        container        INITED    100          0        0      100       0       0
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VERTICES: 05/09  [============>>--------------] 49%   ELAPSED TIME: 1466.88 s
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm very newbie when it comes to hive and databases. Please let me know if any system spec or other information needed

Answer (score 0):

The SQL is complex so it will take time and memory to execute. What we can try is - create separate tables from the subqueries and then use them in outer queries. This will make sure hive doesnt have to do many operations at a time.

Without going into too much details of SQL, here are my suggestions -

1. make a table using subquery sq1. And add this `WHERE SIZE(sq1.itemid) >= 5` condition inside sq1. This will make sure you have a concise data you need.
2. Then using above table, create another table using sq2.
3. Then using above sq2 table, create another table using sq3.
4. use this sq3 in outermost query.

I know this operations can take time (may be longer than original sql ) but it should work and wont fail with memory err if you have a good enough memory. If you see failures even after creating tables, please try to split into more tables.